# Failed to import media from xml file wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress

I am testing a xml file to import . Two sites are mine. So I am just trying to import xml file from a WordPress site to another WordPress site with same theme and in same server. But unfortunately some of media files ( approximately 10) not importing. I don't know why.

I tried it many times. and check all of the links in xml file . Every links are okay there. But still not importing.

Thanks in advance.